# efficient algorithmic method to concatenate rows of an array into a 1-D array

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, numpy

I am using Numpy to manipulate some very strange tabular data. The data entries always come in columns of 1200 entries each.

However, the number of rows always varies. Sometimes the tables I import have 12 rows (i.e. a numpy `ndarray.shape = (12, 1200)`, with 1200 times 12 total entries, i.e. 1200*12 = 14400.) Sometimes the tables have 6 rows (shape = (6, 1200)), and so forth. There's no pattern here.

The number of columns is consistently 1200, but the number of rows always varies. I have no prior knowledge about how many rows, so I cannot write some sort of mathematical formula.

I would like to use `numpy.concatenate` to take each array I am given into a one-dimensional ndarray. (For our example above, that would be shape = (1, 14400). )

So far, for each individual array, I have to individually break it up into N arrays (N = unknown number of rows) and then individually concatenate them.

Or, in order to write a `for` statement, I have to find the number of rows, and manually set the for statement for each array.

Any ideas for a better method? This takes forever.

EDIT: Sorry, mixing together "rows" and "columns". I have re-typed the post above to reflect this. Yes, the arrays are consistently of the shape `(n, 1200). So, the format is`(rows, columns)` and the columns are consistently 1200.

FURTHER QUESTION: My question about `numpy.reshape` is whether the order of the data is changed. So, for an array with 6 rows, shape (6, 1200), will numpy.reshape() return an array shape (1, 72000) such that the original order is preserved? That is,

```
newarray = array([row 1, row 2, row 3, row 4, row 5, row 6])
```

?

Comment: More directly, he says both *"the number of rows always varies"* and *"The number of rows is consistently 1200"*.

Comment: You seem to be mixing rows and columns in your description. Are the arrays consistently `(n,1200)` in shape?

Comment: @hpaulji Yes, the arrays are consistently of the shape `(n, 1200). So, the format is `(rows, columns)` and the columns are consistently 1200.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of ways to address the type of questions you are asking about are:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.ones((6, 12000))

a = np.reshape(x, (1, -1))

b = np.concatenate([x[i,:] for i in range(x.shape[0])])

print x.shape     # (6, 12000)
print a.shape     # (1, 72000)
print b.shape     # (72000,)
```

The advantage of `reshape` is that it doesn't copy the data, so it's fast, but since it's just a new view on the old data, changes to `a` will also change `x`.  Of course, you could also just copy the reshaped array to get separate data.

`concatenate` here will make a copy, but note that the items copied are again just views onto the original `x`, so there's only one copy per element.  Making the concatenated array have shape `(1, 72000)` seems a bit contrived to me so I didn't do it, but it's certainly possible if that's what you really want.

Below is an example for understanding how the ordering works in reshape:

```
x2 = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])
c = np.reshape(x2, (1, -1))

print x2
# [[1 2 3]
#  [4 5 6]
#  [7 8 9]]

print c
#  [[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]]
```

Comment: My question about `numpy.reshape` is whether the order of the data is changed.  So, for an array with 6 rows, shape `(6, 1200)`, will `numpy.reshape()` return an array shape `(1, 72000)` such that the original order is preserved? That is, `arr = array([row 1, row 2, row 3, row 4, row 5, row 6])`?

Comment: @JesseTrevve: I've added an example that shows how the ordering works for `reshape`, which I think is what you want.  (Also, if you wanted the opposite behavior, you could first `transpose` and then `reshape`, all without copying that actual data.)

Comment: Nitpick: though in the case you show, `reshape` does indeed return a view, in general the `reshape` method *does* sometimes copy data, if the results can't be represented with a view. (Example: `x = np.zeros((2, 4))[:, :3]; y = x.reshape(6)`.)

Answer (score 0):

So you have several arrays with shape `(n,1200)`

Make some simpler samples.  It will be easier to see what is going on.

```
a = np.arange(12).reshape(2,6)
#array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
        [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11]])
```

Notice how the numbers increase

```
b = np.arange(18).reshape(3,6)
c = np.concatenate([a,b], axis=0)
```

producing

```
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11],
       [ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17]])
```

Since it is just the 1st dimensions that varies, it has no problem concatenating along this dimension.  `np.vstack` does the same thing.

How about joining the arrays after flattening:

```
np.concatenate([a.flatten(),b.flatten()])
# array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4, 5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17])
```

You'd get the same thing with `c.flatten()`.  (`flatten`, `ravel`, `reshape` all do essentially the same thing.)

```
np.concatenate(c,axis=0)
np.concatenate([c[0,:],c[1,:],c[2,:]...],axis=0)
```

`concatenate` can also be used to `flatten` an array, but this isn't the usual method.  It is, in effect, the same as splitting it by rows and joining those.  Note that `np.vstack(c)` is not the same thing.